# Orbiting target with camera and changing height

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I want to be able to use joystick (left-right) to make the camera orbit around target. I have this handled with the code below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class OrbitCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;

    public float turnSpeed;
    public float height;
    public float distance;

    private Vector3 offsetX;

    void Start()
    {
        offsetX = new Vector3 (0, height, distance);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        offsetX = Quaternion.AngleAxis (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("hOrbit") * turnSpeed, Vector3.down) * offsetX;

        transform.position = target.position + offsetX;
        transform.LookAt (target.position);
    }
}
```

I need to extend this script so that the player can move camera also up and down using the same joystick. So what I want is the camera to be able to move around player in a shape of sphere, always looking at the player. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

## Use a boom camera

A [boom camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jib_(camera)) is wonderfully easy to setup and has a range of convenient cinematic controls:

[image: Visualise a camera boom and things become much simpler]

To set it up, you simply create a new game object which we'll call the [dolly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_dolly). You then simply parent the camera to the dolly and tidy up the positions and rotations:

**Camera**

- Transform: 0,0,-*distance*
- Rotation: 0,0,0

**Dolly**

- Transform: 0,*height*,0
- Rotation: 0,0,0

## Why a boom camera is great

- Rotate the dolly on x and y and you'll get the camera moving in a sphere. *(Note that dragging the rotation gizmo in scene view doesn't show the effect properly because of axis alignment; edit the x/y rotation values in the inspector only)*.
- That -*distance* z value is the *zoom*. Change the local position of the camera to zoom in/out.
- Local rotating the camera gives interesting tilt/pan effects.

## Making it work in your case

You'd attach the script to the dolly gameobject, then use the joystick input to rotate it on x/y:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class OrbitCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    // Height and distance are now set in the scene (by positioning the dolly and changing that camera z value).
    public float turnSpeed;
    private float horizontal;
    private float vertical;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Update horizontal/ vertical angles:
        horizontal += CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("hOrbit") * turnSpeed;

        vertical += CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("vOrbit") * turnSpeed;

        // Update the rotation:
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(horizontal, vertical, 0f);
    }
}
```